# Interlaced or progressive for YouTube?

Tags: video, youtube

For shooting a YouTube videos as a talking head I'm choosing a camera.

The shooting will be indoors. Everything will be calm, no fast movements.
That is talking and occasionally to write something on the whiteboard. Educational videos.

I need Full HD 1080, this is understandable. The question is whether I can shoot as interlaced or progressive is a must?

In other words for the abovementioned purposes must the minimum be 1920x1080/30p or 30i is also possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, there is no reason to shoot interlaced in this digital world. Use P.

Also, if you do not need 30FPS, you could use 24 FPS, that way in your indoor setting, you could use a tiny bit of slower shutter speed, allowing your images to be a bit brighter.

I don't know if you are asking because of some budget constraints on the two models of cameras you are comparing, but 30p will look better than even 60i.